# MYSQL, displaying DML statements and ordering it by desc occurences

Tags: mysql

this is my first time posting a question so sorry for any formatting issues.

I have a piece of code here:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/245bu.png)

but I keep getting an error:
" In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'mysql.gener_log.argument'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

I want to display DML Statements(SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE) from my general_log file while ordering it in descending order.

Much thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group by, just get the count of each in the subquery and order by it in the main query:

```
SELECT DDL_STATEMENT, No_of_DDLs 
FROM
(SELECT 'INSERT' as DDL_STATEMENT, COUNT(*) as No_of_DDLs from mysql.general_log
where argument LIKE ('%INSERT%')
UNION
SELECT 'UPDATE' as DDL_STATEMENT, COUNT(*) as No_of_DDLs from mysql.general_log
where argument LIKE ('%UPDATE%')
UNION
SELECT 'SELECT' as DDL_STATEMENT, COUNT(*) as No_of_DDLs from mysql.general_log
where argument LIKE ('%SELECT%')
UNION
SELECT 'DELETE' as DDL_STATEMENT, COUNT(*) as No_of_DDLs from mysql.general_log
where argument LIKE ('%DELETE%')
) t

ORDER BY No_of_DDLs DESC
```

The query is actually not very accurate, you should add more validations like:

- Using UPPER(argument) to get all combinations of the search term: "SELECT", "select", "Select", etc.
- Excluding words that contain your search terms, e.g. "SELECTION"
- Removing leading "%" in order to get queries that start with the search term. Actually each execution of this very query would create a new hit for each of the 4 search terms :-)